# Cdbcriteria->With, Many To Many Relation And Method Findall(). Strange Behavior

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many, criteria, findall

community!

I need to make a big relational query using many-to-many relations. I've faced a problem when using $criteria->with and findAll() method of the model. Please, explain me what is going on because i've already gone crazy about it. :blink:

I have an Operation model, which is connected to Roles model using many-to-many relation. Here's the relations() method of the Operations model:

```
      public function relations()
    {
            // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
            // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
            return array(
                    'roles' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Roles', 'operations_in_roles(id_oper, id_role)', 'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN'),
            );
    }
```

I have a table in db `operations_in_roles` and everything is working just fine when i'm using the lazy load.

Now, i'm trying to make a relational query using with:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('roles');
$criteria->together = true;            
$criteria->compare('t.id_contr', $cur_contr->id_contr);   
$criteria->select = array('roles.name_role_ru as sosalue_role');

$roles_and_actions = Operations::model()->findAll($criteria);

foreach($roles_and_actions as $key=>$one_record)
        {
            echo $key." "." ".$one_record->id_oper." ".$one_record->sosalue_role."<BR>";
        }
```

the result, which the foreach by findAll() return gives me:

```
  0 38 teacher
  1 39 teacher
  2 40 teacher
  3 41 teacher
```

The query, which is produced by the ar is:

```
    SELECT roles.value_role as sosalue_role, t.id_oper as id_oper, `t`.`id_oper` AS `t0_c0`, `roles`.`id_role` AS `t1_c0`, `roles`.`name_role_ru` AS `t1_c1`, `roles`.`name_role_ua` AS `t1_c2`, `roles`.`value_role` AS `t1_c3`, `roles`.`sort` AS `t1_c4` 
    FROM `operations` `t` 
    INNER JOIN `operations_in_roles` `roles_roles` ON (`t`.`id_oper`=`roles_roles`.`id_oper`) 
    INNER JOIN `roles` `roles` ON (`roles`.`id_role`=`roles_roles`.`id_role`) 
    WHERE (t.id_contr='12')
```

when i'm executing the query in my mysql console or phpmyadmin or so on... the result is right. IT HAS 8 RECORDS, NOT 4!!!

```
0 38 teacher
1 39 teacher
2 40 teacher
3 41 teacher
4 38 admin
5 39 admin
6 40 admin
7 41 admin
```

But why does the findAll() function return me the array of only 4 records? Please, explain, guys!

p.s. I've solved this problem using $criteria->join instead of with and findall returns me the 8 records which it should, but i want to use with in my project...

I want to find the purpose of such strange behavior. Answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in results you have records only for 4 operations. Each operation have 2 roles. So it's a correct behavior for ORM-like solutions. `Operations::model()->findAll` returns 4 operations. If you want to read roles you need the nested loop:

```
foreach($roles_and_actions as $key=>$one_record)
{
    echo $key." "." ".$one_record->id_oper;
    foreach ($one_record->roles as $role) 
    {
        echo $role->name_role_ru;
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need to make an eager load. To get the result i need via 1 query. I had the solution you offer, but i've chosen to refactor it, because of several unneeded queries instead of 1 relational query.

Comment: If you specify with and together options of criteria eager loading must work correctly.

Comment: i've specified with and together from the beginning. see my question please.